About Coreader Comonads
Here [1]  we see a paper that describes when you can compose a directed container over distribution monads.
Here is their definition of a directed container

Here is their definition of the coreader comonad.

A directed container will have a kind of graph structure.  For instance, consider the nonempty list comonad.  Lists are just chains with a head and tail so the graph starts us just chains.  So $S$ is just lists.
What I am wondering about is what is the graph structure of the coreader comonad seen as a directed container?  In particular, I want to know if the graph structure resembles a complete lattice, and hence a dcpo.  What are the restrictions on the set $S$?  For instance, in the binary tree directed container, S is literally binary trees.  What kinds of shapes, $s$, admit a coreader comonad?  What are some examples of coreader commands where we are interested in interesting shapes $S$?  Can we just outright say that $S$ is the set of all dcpos?  Is it possible the positions $P(S) = \{ \top \}$ are the least upper bounds for each dcpo in $S$?
Edit
The coreader comonad is related to the quantum reader monad.  This reader is then based on the complete lattice of protection operators on a hilbert space.  There seems to be something non-trivial to my idea.
[1] Karamlou, Amin, and Nihil Shah. "No Go Theorems: Directed Containers That Do Not Distribute Over Distribution Monads." Proceedings of the 39th Annual ACM/IEEE Symposium on Logic in Computer Science. 2024.

This reminds me of a quote from Kontsevich's "Deformation quantization of Poisson manifolds", which is available on the web: "We denote by $C(V )$ the cofree cocommutative coassociative coalgebra without counit cogenerated by $V$."

Or the comathematician, who turns cotheorems into ffee?

" the nonempty list comonad is just a chain with a head." <-- what does this statement mean? A comonad is a certain kind of functor equipped with some natural transformations satisfying axioms. A "chain with a head" is .. not that. Do you mean to say something like "An algebra for the nonempty list comonad"? It's late here and I'm not going to puzzle this out myself.

Note that the definition of the coreader comonad makes sense for any set S. There are no restrictions on S. ".. is the set of all dcpos?" <--- is this a set, or a proper class? I strongly suggest understanding the construction of the comonad from the "directed container on $[S \triangleleft P]$", so as to unpack the statement in your screenshot, because conflating the two structures (comonads and directed containers) seems to be causing some confusion

It seems that the definition of a directed container in the linked paper just says that a directed container is a category.  In more detail a directed container consists of:

A set $S$
For each $s\in S$, a set $P(s)$ and an element $o_s\in P(s)$
For each $p\in P(s)$, an element $s\downarrow p\in S$
For each $p'\in P(s\downarrow p)$, an element $p\oplus_sp'\in P(s)$
Subject to certain axioms.

These axioms just mean we have a category $\mathcal{C}$ with $\operatorname{obj}(\mathcal{C})=S$, where $\mathcal{C}(s,t)=\{p\in P(s):s\downarrow p=t\}$, and composition is given by $p'\circ p=p\oplus_sp'$.
Given a set $X$ we can define $GX=\coprod_s\prod_t\operatorname{Map}(\mathcal{C}(s,t),X)$.  We define $\epsilon\colon GX\to X$ by $\epsilon(u)=u_s(1_s)$ for $u\in\prod_t\operatorname{Map}(\mathcal{C}(s,t),X)\subseteq GX$.  For such $u$ we also define $\delta(u)\in\prod_t\operatorname{Map}(\mathcal{C}(s,t),GX)\subseteq G^2X$ as follows.  For any $m\in\mathcal{C}(s,t)$, the element $\delta(u)_t(m)$ wil lie in the subset $\prod_r\operatorname{Map}(\mathcal{C}(t,r),X)\subseteq GX$, and will be given by $\delta(u)_t(m)_r(n)=u(n\circ m)$ for all $n\in\mathcal{C}(t,r)$.  This is the natural description of the comonad associated to a directed container.
We can regard $\mathbb{N}$ as a category, with a single morphism from $s$ to $t$ when $s\geq t$.  The associated comonad $G$ is then the nonempty list comonad.
We can regard any set $S$ as a category with only identity morphisms.  The associated comonad is then the coreader comonad.
It seems that the binary tree example can be formulated as follows.  Let $B_\infty$ be the standard infinite binary tree, say with vertex set $\mathbb{N}^+$, where the left branch of $n$ is $2n$ and the right branch is $2n+1$.  We regard this as a partially ordered set with the root at the bottom.  For any $a\in B_\infty$ there is an evident inclusion $f_a\colon B_\infty\to B_\infty$ sending the root to $a$.  By a binary tree we mean a finite subset $T\subseteq B_\infty$ containing the root and closed downwards.  For such $T$ and $a\in T$ we put $T/a=\{t:f_a(t)\in T\}$, so $f_a$ gives an isomorphism from $T/a$ to $\{x\in T: x\geq a\}$.  We can regard the set $\mathcal{C}$ of binary trees as a category with $\mathcal{C}(T_0,T_1)=\{a\in T_0:T_0/a=T_1\}$.  Then $\coprod_{T_1}\mathcal{C}(T_0,T_1)=T_0$, so the associated comonad is $GX=\coprod_{T_0}\operatorname{Map}(T_0,X)$.
The original question is not very clear, but it appears to be asking about a poset or lattice structure on $S$ arising from the directed container structure.  The answer seems to be that in general we have a category structure, which can be regarded as a poset structure only if the morphism sets are subsingletons.  However, the category structure can be arbitrary.
